# Is there a structural difference between Nerve cells in the Somatic and Autonomic Nervous Systems

Tags: neuroscience

Do the actual nerve cells in the Somatic and Autonomic Nervous Systems have a different structure or chemical make up or are they the same thing just separate systems?

Comment: Welcome to P&N SE! Yes there are differences. Have you found any yourself while researching this question? Most textbooks have info on that (e.g. polarity, myelination).

Comment: No, that's why I asked this question. All I can find is descriptions of the different areas or body functions they cover.